# Multiple dex files define Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceClient;

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to use Amazon AWS SDK in my Android app. The app already uses C2Call SDK. The app is working, but as soon as I add AWS gradle libraries, it starts giving me Multiple Dex file exception. I searched for it and got to know that it is related to a single library defined multiple times, however I am not sure which one is it, from the log. I tried removing different gradle compile option and whenever I add an AWS library, it gives the Multiple Dex Exception.

Here's my App's gradle file -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    /*compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'*/
    compile(name: 'lib-c2callsdk', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ses:2.2.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.3'
}
```

I tried with adding and removing appcompact too.

Here's the error log I am getting -

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Warning:Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLibC2callsdkLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDexDebug
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$5) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.a.d) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceClient;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 25.398 secs
Information:1 error
Information:2 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

If I select just one of the AWS libraries such as cognito, it gives the same exception without those long warnings.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here and how can I find the exact issue?

**Update:**

I have tried putting the following in the app's gradle -

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    /*compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'*/
    compile(name: 'lib-c2callsdk', ext: 'aar'){
        exclude group:'gson'
        exclude group:'commons-logging'
    }
    compile ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'){
        exclude group:'gson'
        exclude group:'commons-logging'
    }
    /*compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ses:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'*/
    /*compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'*/
}
```

And now the error is reduced to this -

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLibC2callsdkLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceClient;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.804 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: add this in defaultConfig
    multiDexEnabled true

Comment: @justDroid Thanks for the quick response. I tried it now, but I am getting the following error after adding the option -      
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class

Comment: sorry that was not the answer for you.
do you have added this lib commons-logging:commons-logging?
it conflicts because amazon also using that.

Comment: @justDroid Not knowingly, but if I remove other aws dependencies and keep it just one, the warning goes away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says `com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient` is defined multiple times. It's likely that you have several copies of AWS Android SDK referenced in your project, one from Maven apparently. Would you please double check there isn't another one under the libs folder? I am not familiar with c2call. Not sure if there is something in it conflicting with AWS SDK. One way to check is to unzip jars and search for a particular class. Here is an example:

```
unzip -l *.jar | grep AmazonWebServiceClient
```

As for the warning, just feel free to ignore it. AWS Android SDK depends on apache-commons-logging 1.1.1 which is compiled with JDK 1.5. Android doesn't like it but can live with it.

Comment: I am on Windows, but I converted the aar into zip and the classes.jar in it to zip again and extracted and found that there's indeed an `com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient` present in the C2Call library. I have no idea why is it there.
So if I want to use AWS libraries, how can I do that?

Comment: It looks like c2call needs AWS. You can ask them to repackage the AWS library under a different package, or you can do it yourself with Jarjar https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/.

Comment: I did it myself. Thanks for the suggestion. I used jarjar to refactor the classes, so that it no longer conflicts with AWS. I had to refactor Gson package too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to solve it (to help those who might need the steps in future) -

1. Change AAR file extension to zip and extract it.
2. Open the Extracted folder to find classes.jar
3. Download [JarJar.jar](https://jarjar.googlecode.com)
4. Create a Rule File where you can mention which package or class needs to be refactored. Here's my rule file -

   ```
   rule com.amazonaws.services.s3.a.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.a.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazonaws.services.s3.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazonaws.sdk.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazonaws.regions.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.xerces.impl.msg.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazonaws.http.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazonaws.e.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazonaws.d.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazonaws.c.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazonaws.b.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazonaws.a.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazonaws.auth.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazonaws.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazon.device.messaging.development.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazon.device.messaging.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.amazon.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.google.gson.stream.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.google.gson.reflect.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.google.gson.internal.bind.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.google.gson.internal.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.google.gson.annotations.* com.jarjar.@0
   rule com.google.gson.* com.jarjar.@0
   ```
5. Run the jarjar.jar. Here's a sample command -

   ```
   java -jar "D:\Android\Dev Tools\jarjar-1.4.jar" process jarjarrules.txt lib-c2callsdk\classes.jar classes.jar
   ```
6. Copy the resultant classes.jar and convert the copy into a zip. Extract it to verify the refactoring.
7. Now Copy the resultant classes.jar and replace the old classes.jar with it in the extracted library folder.
8. Compress the folder to a zip(remember to have classes.jar on the root.
9. Rename the zip to aar extension.
10. Use the new aar library in your project.

PS: Of Course, thanks to Yangfan for suggesting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am using AWS rekognition library for image recognition

I have faced the same issue while using

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-rekognition:1.11.66
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.4.4
```

In android studio, I have solved by replacing the dependencies 
 `implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.4.4` by [jar file](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-android-sdk-rekognition/2.3.8) 
.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
implementation files('yourJarFileLocation/AmazonRekognition/lib/aws-android-sdk-rekognition-2.6.9.jar')
```

}

Next just clean, rebuild, run. It worked